# Getting error org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am automating a web page (using Selenium with Java) where I have to click on a button on the webpage. After clicking the button, a new window opens up and I am able to switch to the new window using Window handles. However, the new window consists of a data table, whose all entries are hidden in the form:

```
<tr class="tdtable_even_row">
    <td class="tablebody1">
        <input type="hidden" name="createdBy[0]" value="TESTOR02"> 
        TESTOR02 
        <br> 
        <input type="hidden" name="createdTimestamp[0]" value="JAN 30, 2023"> 
        JAN 30, 2023 
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="tablebody1">
        <input type="hidden" name="text[0]" value="Test Agreement Text Six"> 
        Test Agreement Text Six 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when I am searching this value in console using >> **document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=hidden]").value**, I am getting the correct output. However, when I am running this through automation script >>

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String text = (String) js.executeScript("document.querySelector('tbody > tr.tdtable_even_row > td:nth-child(2) > input').value");
System.out.println(text);
```

I am getting the error >> **org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')**

Any inputs as to why automation is giving the error but browser console is giving correct output and how to fix this?

I tried to get the desire output through automation as is displayed in browser console, however error is being displayed in automation script

Comment: are you aware that the selectors are completely different?

Comment: So, we can’t use query selector in javascript? Any inputs on how to extract this hidden element using javascript since I can’t find it using selenium as web element is hidden

Comment: I think you are not returning any value from executeScript function. You could try with adding a return statement i.e. String text = (String) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('tbody > tr.tdtable_even_row > td:nth-child(2) > input').value");

Comment: @saurabh060 [`querySelector` returns `null` if no `element` is found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) that matches the [`selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#parameters). Hence the error tells you that `null.value` cannot be accessed

Comment: @SrinivasuKaki: I tried with return as well and got same results

Comment: @Aleksandar: The problem here is that the selenium Java automation code is picking the same JS code and giving null.value but if I run the same JS code in browser console, it gives correct value

Comment: @saurabh060 are you able to identify any other objects on the new window that’s opened?